# R - how to nest data frame over a group in parallel cores

Tags: r, parallel-processing, dplyr, tidyr

Any idea how I can run the following operation in parallel cores?

### libraries and sample data

```
libs <- c("plyr", "dplyr", "tidyr")
sapply(libs, require, character.only = T)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:10, 100000, TRUE), value = runif(100000))
```

### operation to run in parallel cores:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest()
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Do you want each group to be run on a different core? Other than `nest`, is there some other operation you want to perform on the data, like `sum`, `summary`, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using multiple cores to simply nest a `data.frame` wouldn't be efficient. So I assume you want to perform some other calculation. The example below calculates the `summary`, which will have several values for each group id.

The `multidplyr` package convenient for this kind of thing.

```
# replace plyr with multidplyr
libs <- c("dplyr", "tidyr",'multidplyr')
devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")
sapply(libs, require, character.only = T)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(1:10, 100000, TRUE), 
                 value = runif(100000))%>%as.tbl

# first the single core solution. No need to nest, 
# since group_by%>%do() automatically nests.
x<-df%>% 
  group_by(id)%>%
  # nest()%>%
  do(stat_summary=summary(.$value)%>%as.matrix%>%t%>%data.frame%>%as.tbl)%>%
  ungroup  

# next, multiple core solution
n_cores<-2
cl<-multidplyr::create_cluster(n_cores)
# you have to load the packages into each cluster
cluster_library(cl,c('dplyr','tidyr')) 
df_mp<-df%>%multidplyr::partition(cluster = cl,id) # group by id

x_mp<-df_mp%>% 
  do(stat_summary=summary(.$value)%>%as.matrix%>%t%>%data.frame%>%as.tbl)%>%
  collect()%>%
  ungroup
```

Results match. You probably won't get much speed up unless your doing a calculation that is slower than loading the data to each different processes.

```
all.equal(unnest(x_mp),unnest(x))
x_mp

TRUE
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id     stat_summary
   <int>           <list>
 1     3 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 2     5 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 3     6 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 4     7 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 5     1 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 6     2 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 7     4 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 8     8 <tibble [1 x 6]>
 9     9 <tibble [1 x 6]>
10    10 <tibble [1 x 6]>
```

Comment: thanks @dule aranux I didn't knew about the multidplyr package, could solve my problem..